# Install 2 sonar qube servers on same machine

Tags: sonarqube

I have a machine with rhel 6.9 that has a sonar qube server 5.4 installed that is using mysql as database and working properly.

I want to install another instance of sonar qube server , but this time version 5.6.7.To do this , i have followed  tips given in this question:
[2 instances of Sonar on same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558915/2-instances-of-sonar-on-same-machine)

Due to  mysql version installed i cant use mysql as database so i decided to use the default H2 database just to test it.
i have changed  ports configuration so they dont collide.

SONAR 5.4 CONF:

```
sonar.web.host=10.12.19.21
sonar.web.port=9000
sonar.search.port=9001
sonar.web.context: /
```

SONAR 5.6.7 CONF:

```
sonar.web.host=10.12.19.21
sonar.web.port=9002
sonar.search.port=9003
sonar.web.context: /sonar 
sonar.embeddedDatabase.port=9093
```

If i try to star the 5.6.7 sonar server i get this database conector error:

> 2018.05.30 11:12:18 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/temp
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:18 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /datos/build_tools/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/bin/java
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/temp -javaagent:/datos/build_tools/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
>   -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/temp/sq-process6424563207579224247properties
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:19 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:19 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9003
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:19 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1527671537972] version[1.7.5], pid[3436],
>   build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:19 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1527671537972] initializing ...
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:19 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1527671537972] loaded [], sites []
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:19 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1527671537972] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/datos
>   (/dev/mapper/VGDatos-LVDatos)]], net usable_space [6.6gb], net
>   total_space [49gb], types [ext4]
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:21 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:22 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1527671537972] initialized
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:22 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1527671537972] starting ...
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:22 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1527671537972] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9003]}, publish_address
>   {inet[/127.0.0.1:9003]}
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:22 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1527671537972] sonarqube/Wg5KZn3xSpmeh0JtOAurvg
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:25 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1527671537972] new_master
>   [sonar-1527671537972][Wg5KZn3xSpmeh0JtOAurvg][localhost.localdomain][inet[/127.0.0.1:9003]]{rack_id=sonar-1527671537972},
>   reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:25 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1527671537972] started
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:25 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1527671537972] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:30 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:30 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /datos/build_tools/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/bin/java
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/temp -javaagent:/datos/build_tools/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
>   -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/jdbc/h2/h2-1.3.176.jar
>   org.sonar.server.app.WebServer
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/temp/sq-process6429413134538078019properties
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:31 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:31 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:31 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10.12.19.21-9002"]
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:31 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:48 INFO  web[o.a.c.u.SessionIdGeneratorBase] Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG]
>   took [16,742] milliseconds.
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6.7 / ca9cfc3437a251cd081c75971790912b081acc64
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:50 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Starting embedded database on port 9093 with url
>   jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9093/sonar
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:50 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database started. Data stored in: /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/data
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:50 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9093/sonar
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:51 WARN  web[o.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:53 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1527671537972] loaded [], sites []
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin C# / 5.0 / 17ddb09047940791828dcb70c9e225f006ab11aa
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Git / 1.2 / a713dd64daf8719ba4e7f551f9a1966c62690c17
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 3.13.1 / cf0f0c950ba3e83a87c7fe11c6ff7e63f4864bd9
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JavaScript / 2.11 / a9b1afa9ceef7079811779d9efc5f8026acb1400
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.3 / aff503d48bc77b07c2b62abf93249d0a20bd355c
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:55 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:55 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1527671537972] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on
>   [Wg5KZn3xSpmeh0JtOAurvg][sonar-1527671537972] free: 6.6gb[13.5%],
>   replicas will not be assigned to this node
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no
>   proxy)
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
>
> 2018.05.30 11:12:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
>
> 2018.05.30 11:13:00 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
>
> 2018.05.30 11:13:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register measure filters
>
> 2018.05.30 11:13:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboards
>
> 2018.05.30 11:13:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
>
> 2018.05.30 11:13:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
>
> 2018.05.30 11:13:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index activities
>
> 2018.05.30 11:13:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index issues
>
> 2018.05.30 11:13:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index tests
>
> 2018.05.30 11:13:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index users
>
> 2018.05.30 11:13:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index views
>
> 2018.05.30 11:13:01 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_171-b11
>   [linux-amd64]
>   2018.05.30 11:13:01 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
>   **START OF ERROR**
>
> **2018.05.30 11:13:15 INFO  web[jruby.rack] An exception happened during JRuby-Rack startup jdbc adapter requires :driver and :url (got :driver**
>   **= )**
>
> --- System jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_171-b11 [linux-amd64] Time: Wed May
>   30 11:13:15 +0200 2018 Server: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 jruby.home:
>   file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home
>
> --- Context Init Parameters: jruby.compat.version = 1.8 jruby.max.runtimes = 1 jruby.min.runtimes = 1 jruby.rack.logging =
>   slf4j process.index = 2 process.key = web process.sharedDir =
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/temp process.terminationTimeout = 60000
>   rails.env = production sonar.ce.javaAdditionalOpts = 
>   sonar.ce.javaOpts = -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true sonar.cluster.name = sonarqube sonar.core.startedAt = 1527671538155 sonar.embeddedDatabase.port =
>   9093 sonar.jdbc.driverPath =
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/jdbc/h2/h2-1.3.176.jar sonar.jdbc.maxActive
>   = 60 sonar.jdbc.maxIdle = 5 sonar.jdbc.maxWait = 5000 sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 600000 sonar.jdbc.minIdle = 2
>   sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 30000 sonar.jdbc.url =
>   jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9093/sonar sonar.node.name =
>   sonar-1527671537972 sonar.path.data = /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/data
>   sonar.path.home = /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7 sonar.path.logs =
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/logs sonar.path.temp =
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/temp sonar.path.web =
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web sonar.search.host = 127.0.0.1
>   sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts =  sonar.search.javaOpts = -Xmx1G
>   -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError sonar.search.port = 9003 sonar.svn.use_merge_history = false
>   sonar.web.context = /sonar sonar.web.host = 10.12.19.21
>   sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts =  sonar.web.javaOpts = -Xmx512m -Xms128m
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true sonar.web.port = 9002
>
> --- Backtrace ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: jdbc adapter requires :driver and :url (got :driver = )
>           setup_jdbc_factory at /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:89
>   setup_connection_factory at
>   /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:59
>                   initialize at /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:14
>                   initialize at /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:76
>                          new at /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:44
>              jdbc_connection at /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:12
>                         send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227
>               new_connection at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223
>   checkout_new_connection at
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245
>                     checkout at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188
>                         loop at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519
>                     checkout at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184
>              mon_synchronize at jar:file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191
>                     checkout at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183
>                   connection at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98
>          retrieve_connection at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326
>          retrieve_connection at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123
>                   connection at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115
>                   initialize at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440
>                           up at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401
>                      migrate at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383
>            upgrade_and_start at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:66
>              automatic_setup at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:77
>                       (root) at /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:306
>                         load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094
>                       (root) at file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1
>             load_environment at file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25
>             load_environment at file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79
>
> --- RubyGems Gem.dir: /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems Gem.path: /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems
>   /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0 /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global
>   Activated gems:   activesupport-2.3.15   activerecord-2.3.15
>   rack-1.1.6   actionpack-2.3.15   rails-2.3.15   color-tools-1.3.0
>   i18n-0.7.0   json-jruby-1.2.3-universal-java-1.6
>   activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20   arel-7.0.0   fastercsv-1.4.0
>
> --- Bundler undefined method `bundle_path' for Bundler:Module
>
> --- JRuby-Rack Config compat_version = RUBY1_8 default_logger = org.jruby.rack.logging.StandardOutLogger@3bf0099a equals = 
>   err = java.io.PrintStream@12518053 filter_adds_html = true
>   filter_verifies_resource = false ignore_environment = false
>   initial_memory_buffer_size =  initial_runtimes = 1
>   jms_connection_factory =  jms_jndi_properties =  logger =
>   org.jruby.rack.logging.Slf4jLogger@3bd3eab9 logger_class_name = slf4j
>   logger_name = jruby.rack maximum_memory_buffer_size = 
>   maximum_runtimes = 1 num_initializer_threads =  out =
>   java.io.PrintStream@59e52324 rackup =  rackup_path =  rewindable =
>   true runtime_arguments =  runtime_environment = 
>   runtime_timeout_seconds =  serial_initialization = false
>   servlet_context =
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@3f63b540
>   throw_init_exception = false
>
> **2018.05.30 11:13:15 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/sonar]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   org.sonar.server.platform.RubyRailsContextListener
>   org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: jdbc adapter requires
>   :driver and :url (got :driver = )     from**
>   /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:89:in
>   `setup_jdbc_factory'  from
>   /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:59:in`
>   setup_connection_factory'    from
>   /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:14:in
>   `initialize'  from
>   /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:76:in`
>   initialize'  from
>   /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:44:in
>   `new'     from
>   /home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:12:in`
>   jdbc_connection'     from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'   from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in`
>   new_connection'  from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in
>   `checkout_new_connection'     from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in`
>   checkout'    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519:in `loop'   from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in`
>   checkout'    from
>   jar:file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in
>   `mon_synchronize'     from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in`
>   checkout'    from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in
>   `connection'  from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in`
>   retrieve_connection'     from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in
>   `retrieve_connection'     from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in`
>   connection'  from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440:in
>   `initialize'  from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in`
>   up'  from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in
>   `migrate'     from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:66:in`
>   upgrade_and_start'   from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:77:in
>   `automatic_setup'     from
>   /datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:306:in`
>   (root)'  from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094:in `load'   from
>   file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1:in`
>   (root)'  from
>   file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25:in
>   `load_environment'    from
>   file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79:in`
>   load_environment'
>
> at
>   org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:29)
>   ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]     at
>   org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98)
>   ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]     at
>   org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50)
>   ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]     at
>   org.sonar.server.platform.RubyRailsContextListener.contextInitialized(RubyRailsContextListener.java:38)
>   ~[sonar-server-5.6.7.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [na:1.8.0_171]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_171]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_171]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [na:1.8.0_171] Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException:
>   (ConnectionNotEstablished) jdbc adapter requires :driver and :url (got
>   :driver = )   at
>   RUBY.setup_jdbc_factory(/home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:89)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.setup_connection_factory(/home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:59)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.initialize(/home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:14)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.initialize(/home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:76)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.new(/home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:44)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.jdbc_connection(/home/desa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:12)
>   ~[na:na]  at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227)
>   ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]    at
>   RUBY.new_connection(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.checkout_new_connection(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.checkout(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188)
>   ~[na:na]  at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519)
>   ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]    at
>   RUBY.checkout(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.mon_synchronize(jar:file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.checkout(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.connection(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.retrieve_connection(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.retrieve_connection(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.connection(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.initialize(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440) ~[na:na]     at
>   RUBY.up(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401) ~[na:na]     at
>   RUBY.migrate(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383) ~[na:na]    at
>   RUBY.upgrade_and_start(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:66)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.automatic_setup(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:77)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.(root)(/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:306)
>   ~[na:na]  at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094)
>   ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]    at
>   RUBY.(root)(file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.load_environment(file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   RUBY.load_environment(file:/datos/sonarqube-5.6.7/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79) ~[na:na]
>   2018.05.30 11:13:15 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
>   appropriate container log file
>   2018.05.30 11:13:15 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [/sonar] startup failed due to previous errors

Does anyone know why happens this error?
It seems like a ruby error but requirements of sonar doesnt talk about having  ruby installed.

Comment: Did you install the two versions in a separate directory? Also clean all tmp directories before starting. You also cannot use the default H2 database in production. A custom installation of Ruby is not needed.

Comment: They are installed in separated directories . I have cleared both temp folder  but didnt work at all.Same problem